How do you set up a system wide Proxy system for multiple SSH Dynamic Port (SOCKS5) Connections
What I'm trying to do is create a FoxyProxy type system wide proxy system for SSH Dynamic ports. My starting point is a OpenBSD Unix Based system, but has a lot of RedHat based additions. All of the systems I contact are RedHat-Based Linux. I cannot have a paid solution due to corp restrictions
I've been looking for a couple days now for a solution, & while I've seen many single Proxy solutions (quite a few using FoxyProxy), I can't find anything for what I'm looking at! I need to be able to map URL's and forwarding patterns w/o the need for FoxyProxy
The situation:
I have to admin systems all over the country. Each local Bastion has its own set of Forward & reverse SSH ports set up automatically. I've set up My own SSH forwards to get to systems beyond & have a separate Dynamic SOCKS5 (-D) port set up to get to Web servers only accessible thru those Bastions.
Currently I have 3 Dynamic ports; 8888, 9999, & 9098 set up that are forwarded thru the Bastion set forwarded ports
Initial Bastion Connection:
Host Initial
  Hostname F.Q.D.N.OfHost
  User User
  ForwardX11 yes
  ControlMaster no
  # VPN Tunnels set by the Bastion
  # Set a local port to forward to the Bastion Port
  LocalForward  2235 localhost:327885
  # Pipe the Remote Forward Back to me
  RemoteForward 42785 localhost:22


Followed by a SOCKS connection to get to the Back End system
Host D-Web
    #Connect to the local Bastion Tunnel
    HostName localhost
    Port 2235 
    User User
    # And set a SOCKS Proxy thru there
    DynamicForward localhost:8888

I have 3 proxies set in FoxyProxy (one for each port) and have set the URLs & patterns that need to be fowarded thru those.
Unfortunately, this forces me thru Firefox for all my Web Work. All the Job e-mails & documents are all Goggle Workspace based. This eventually forces me thru Chrome if I use the "Separate" Apps for Mail & meetings (FoxyProxy leaves much to be desired on Chrome).
I want to have a system-wide Browser Agnostic set of Proxy forward rules so I don't have to be forced to use any one Browser.
Any documentation or solutions would be highly appreciated
